# Calling certain length of elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

**Python**

I have a list with 5 elements. Each element has 2042 rows and 2 columns`(2042,2)`.The variable type is numpy.ndarray. I want to call on the first element (`data[0]`) and the first 1440 rows in the second column. So the format right now is `data[0][0,1]`, which gives me the value in the first row and second column for the first element. How do I write a line to give me the first 1440 rows?

Something like `data[0][0:1439,1]`, which I know doesn't work--but to that effect.

Comment: What is the data type in the list? Numpy array?

Comment: What doesn't work about your code snippet? Is it just missing the 1440th row?

Comment: I was adding an extra set of brackets in the code I was working with.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a numpy array, then

```
data[0][:1440,1]
```

Should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Well, its difficult to assume what has been your approach.

But taking that:

```
data = [[[i for i in range(2042)] for i in range(2)] for i in range(5)]
```

The best aproximation to obtain the first 1440 rows in second column, of first element is:

```
data[0][1][:1440]
```

Regards!